# Skipping print but continuing program

Tags: python-2.7

So I have an assignment:

Your friend wants to try to make a word ladder! This is a list of words where each word has a one-letter difference from the word before it. Here’s an example:

cat
cot
cog
log
Write a program to help your friend.

It should do the following:

Ask your friend for an initial word

Repeatedly ask them for an index and a letter

You should replace the letter at the index they provided with the letter they enter You should then print the new word

Stop asking for input when the user enters -1 for the index

Here’s what should be happening behind the scenes:

You should have a function, get_index, that repeatedly asks the user for an index until they enter a valid integer that is within the acceptable range of indices for the initial string. 
(If they enter a number out of range, you should reply invalid index.)

You should have another function, get_letter, that repeatedly asks the user for a letter until they enter exactly one lowercase letter. (If they enter more than one character, you should reply Must be exactly one character!. If they enter a capital letter, you should reply Character must be a lowercase letter!.)

You should store a list version of the current word in a variable. This is what you should update each time the user swaps out a new letter.

Each time you have to print the current word, print the string version of the list you are keeping in your variable.

I have tried rewriting, researching, and even debug mode.

```
def get_index():
    while True:
        index_in = int(input("Enter a number between 0 and " + str(len(string) - 1) + ": "))
        if index_in > len(string) or index_in < -1:
            print "Invalid Index"
        elif index_in == -1:
            return False
        else:
            get_letter(index_in)

def get_letter(index):
    global string
    char_list = list(string)
    while True:
        letter = input("Enter a letter: ")
        if letter.isupper():
            print "Character must be lower case!"
        else:
            char_list[index] = letter
            string = ('').join(char_list)
            break
    print string


string = input("Enter a word: ")
get_index()
```

An example of the program should look like this:

Enter a word: cat

Enter an index (-1 to quit): 1

Enter a letter: o

cot

Enter an index (-1 to quit): 2

Enter a letter: g

cog

Enter an index (-1 to quit): 5

Invalid index

Enter an index (-1 to quit): -3

Invalid index

Enter an index (-1 to quit): 0

Enter a letter: L

Character must be a lowercase letter!

Enter a letter: l

log

Enter an index (-1 to quit): -1

Comment: what is the problem you a re facing?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. You may want to read [ask] and [mcve] and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code looks perfect!
Just need some changes according to (python 3)

```
def get_index():
    while True:
        index_in = int(input("Enter a number between 0 and " + str(len(string) - 1) + " (-1 to quit): "))
        if index_in > len(string) -1 or index_in < -1:
            print("Invalid Index")
        elif index_in == -1:
            return False
        else:
            get_letter(index_in)

def get_letter(index):
    global string
    char_list = list(string)
    while True:
        letter = input("Enter a letter: ")
        if letter.isupper():
            print("Character must be lower case!")
        else:
            char_list[index] = letter
            string = ('').join(char_list)
            break
    print(string)
    return



string = input("Enter a word: ")
get_index()
```

You should use **print(msg)** instead of print msg in python 3

**You missed one condition**, consider this scenario,

Run the program

Enter a word: c

Enter a number between 0 and 0 (-1 to quit): 1

**Error**

there was a wrong in get_index() check on line:

```
if index_in > len(string) or index_in < -1:
```

it should be :

```
if index_in > len(string) -1 or index_in < -1:
```

- ============================================================ *

**UPDATE**

updating the annwer according to discussion in comments:

```
def get_index(string):
    try:
        while True:
            index_in = int(input("Enter a number between 0 and " + str(len(string) - 1) + " (-1 to quit): "))
            if index_in > len(string) -1 or index_in < -1:
                print("Invalid Index")
            elif index_in == -1:
                return False
            else:
                get_letter(index_in, string)
    except ValueError:
        print("Please Enter a number!")
        get_index(string)

def get_letter(index, string):
    char_list = list(string)
    while True:
        letter = input("Enter a letter: ")
        if letter.isupper():
            print("Character must be lower case!")
        else:
            char_list[index] = letter
            string = ('').join(char_list)
            break
    print(string)
    return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    string = input("Enter a word: ")
    get_index(string)
```

**CHANGES are:**

1. You must avoid global variables.

   Instead, pass particular variable to functions as argumens.
    Notice, how `string`  was used in first answer and how it was used in the updated answer.
2. Use try-catch blocks to catch unexpected behavior

Comment: yes, agree.. it's not perfect, but let's appreciate his efforts and motivate him by guiding him.

Comment: "guiding" would imply teaching good practices (avoiding globals, having a correct execution flow, etc).

Comment: yes, I agree with your suggestion -  "global should be avoided".  I will update the answer accordingly.